# Chromecast 2 with ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

I recently purchased chromecast 2 and wanted to use it with Ubuntu 18.04. I searched here and saw all answers were from 2013 and nothing works. There is also an addon on chrome apps but that is old and discontinued. ([Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-cast/boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd))

Anyone here using chromecast 2 with ubuntu 18.04 ? This will be of great help

Comment: Do you want to cast to or from the Ubuntu system? What is the other system in the scenario (smart TV/Phone)?

Comment: Basically want to cast media, browser(just like android) to chromecast i.e. ultimately to my TV.

Comment: There are some other Chromecast plugins on the Chrome Web Store that are not discontinued https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/chromecast. I can't vouch for any, but worth a try perhaps.

Comment: Most of them are not updated and I hope someone here knows better solution, otherwise I will give them a try. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casting from Chrome to Chromecast is now native function, **you don't need any plugins**. Just open options menu on the right and choose "Cast...". After click I can see both of my network Chromecasts (including Chromecast Audio).

[image: cast menu]

Comment: I am using ubunt 19.10 and Chromium Versão 80.0.3987.100 (Versão oficial) snap 64 bits. The Cast never finds the Chromecast.